# EntityType Form SYmfony add as Entity instead of int

Tags: php, forms, symfony, entity, symfony-forms

I'm here because I can't find a solution to my problem. I have a form in Symfony 6 and one of the value is id_client and reffer to another entity, Client (relation ManyToOne).

I tested few methods to make the field be a select choice of all the clients (I show the name of the client). And every of them works but when I submit the form this value is add as the whole entity and not just the id. This is a problem because I end with this:

`Expected argument of type "int", "App\\Entity\\Client" given at property path "id_client".`

In my form it looks like this:

```
<?php

namespace App\Form;

use App\Entity\Client;
use App\Entity\Group;
use App\Repository\ClientRepository;
use Symfony\Bridge\Doctrine\Form\Type\EntityType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;
use Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\OptionsResolver;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\CheckboxType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\ChoiceType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\TextType;
class Group1Type extends AbstractType
{
    private $clientRepository;

    public function __construct(ClientRepository $clientRepository)
    {
        $this->clientRepository = $clientRepository;
        $this->clients = $clientRepository->findAll();
    }

    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options): void
    {
        $builder
            ->add('name', TextType::class, [
                'attr' => [
                    'class' => 'form-control'
                ],
                'label' => 'Name: '
            ])
            ->add('can_display', CheckboxType::class, [
                'label' => 'Can display : ',
                'attr' => [
                    'class' => 'my-3 mx-2'
                ]
            ])
            ->add('id_client', EntityType::class, [
                'class' => Client::class,
                // 'choices' => $this->clientRepository->findAllNameAlphabetical(),
                // 'query_builder' => function (ClientRepository $client) {
                //     return $client->findAllNameAlphabetical();
                // },
                'choice_label' => 'name',
                'expanded' => false,
                'multiple' => false,
                'attr' => [
                    'class' => 'form-control'
                ]
            ])
        ;
    }

    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver): void
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults([
            'data_class' => Group::class,
        ]);
    }
}
```

The twig:

```
<section class="container my-3">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col">
            {{ form_start(form) }}
                {{ form_row(form.name) }}
                {{ form_row(form.can_display) }}
                {{ form_row(form.id_client) }}
                <button class="btn btn-primary my-3">{{ button_label|default('Save') }}</button>
            {{ form_end(form) }}
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
```

The controller (I have the same result if I let it as it was at the beginning):

```
#[Route('/new', name: 'app_group_new', methods: ['GET', 'POST'])]
    public function new(Request $request, GroupRepository $groupRepository): Response
    {
        $group = new Group();
        $form = $this->createForm(Group1Type::class, $group);
        $form->handleRequest($request);
        // $group->id_client = $group->id_client->id;
        
        if ($form->isSubmitted()) {
            // dd('submit');
            // if(gettype($group->id_client)=="Client"){
                // dd($group);
                if($form->isValid()){
                    dd('valid');
                    $groupRepository->save($group, true);
                    $this->addFlash('success', 'The creation went successfully.');
                    return $this->redirectToRoute('app_group_index', [], Response::HTTP_SEE_OTHER);
                // }
            }
        }

        return $this->renderForm('group/new.html.twig', [
            'group' => $group,
            'form' => $form,
        ]);
    }
```

My entity:

```
    #[ORM\Column]
    private ?int $id_client = null;
```

Comment: If you only want an id, then you shouldn't use `EntityType`, since that always converts an `id` to an entity and then returns the entity. You could use a `ChoiceType` instead, since that doesn't do the automatic conversion. But are you sure your entities are set up correctly? I would expect `Group` to have a `$client` property that holds a `Client` object, and then the ORM would do the conversion of the `Client` object to a `id_client` when storing it in the database.

Comment: If $id_client has a relation why do you want to save an int instead of the Client entity? You are mixing concepts, if you want to save a entity client you should have ``` private ?Client $id_client = null; ``` then you can use EntityType in the form, otherwise use ChoiceType in the form without defining the class attribute.

Comment: You miss out multiple concepts of symfony and doctrine here. I really recommend you to read the [Symfony documentation](https://symfony.com/doc/current/index.html). After 2 years of developing in Symfony I still use it every day and I love it. Its aweseome!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your entity, do not name properties with `id_*`. The client-Property in the Group(?) Entity should be named `$client`, not `$id_client`.

Then, in your Form, name that field excactly like the property in the Group-Entity. Doctrine (as a DBAL should do) does that behind-the-scene relating of the object by the actual id for you.

**Group1Type.php**

```php
    ->add('client', EntityType::class, [
        'class' => Client::class,
        // ...
    ])
```

And your **Group-Entity** (or Group1?)

```php
class Group
{
    // ...

    #[ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity: Client::class, inversedBy: 'groups')]
    #[ORM\JoinColumn(nullable: false)]
    private $client;

    // ...
}
```

> It is totallfy fine and correct that the Form it self submits and handles the Entity-Instance of the selected client. You almost never handle `$id` values. Thats one of the features of doctrine!

> See the [Symfony documentation](https://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/entity.html) for more information on how to use `EntityType` fields.

---

> **Note:** From the naming you gave, **I suspect** you have the **wrong relation**, maybe it should be `OneToMany`? (Can you tell us how `Group` and `Client` is related? Does 1 Group have multiple clients or vice versa?)

---

> **Sidenote:** In rare cases, when you really need a Number related to an Entity (e.g. a textinput where user can enter a customer number which then translates to a real customer entity) you can use `DataTransformer` to translate such values. **But this is not what you want here!**

Comment: Thanks for yours answers Jonathan, alex and Marleen.

- When I put ChoiceType instead of ENtityType I got the same result.

- For my relations, Each client can have multiples Groups

- Why do I have an' int id_client' instead of an 'Client client' ? --> I don't know, I store them has type relation and ended with that ... so I don't know. This happened to all my relations in all my Entitys. Should I restart and make new entities with relation again and see what I have ?

Comment: I suggest you make your entites with the `make` command `php bin/console make entity`. If `1` `Client` has `n` `Group`s a `OneToMany` relation is correct. You really want to go with an `EntityType` form field here.

Comment: Do not take this topic (ids or object relation) as an optional choice. Many features depend on this being done correctly (e.g. validation, form fields, migrations, repositories and everywhere you use these entities in your controllers)

Answer (score -1):

simple solution is to use choice type, this way you dont need the relation and when you submit you will have the id of the client. If load the form for editing (loading the entity, it will show the selected value from the submit)

```
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options): void
{
  $builder
     ->add('client', ChoiceType::class, [
                'choices'=> $this->getClients(),
    ])
}
public function getClients(){
 $conn = $this->getEntityManager()->getConnection();
 $query = "SELECT `name`, `id` FROM `clients` order by `name`";
 $stmt = $conn->executeQuery($query);
 return $stmt->fetchAllKeyValue(); 
 }
```

it will generate a dropdown menu where the value is the id, and the option is the client name

Comment: I strongly advice **against** using plain queries! **This solution is extremely bad.** Please refer to the documentation where everything is statet correctly.

Comment: can you argument your advice against plain queries ? in the documentation is written that they can be used @Jonathan

Comment: Well first of all if your table schema changes, the doctrine's `findBy()` method would still be able to fetch - lets say - newly related tables, or additional columns. Plain Queries on the other hand are like *set in stone*. You **can** use them, but in years I never had to, because one can always use a repository to fetch the data and let doctrine do all the (dynamic) stuff for you. Additionally, a `FormType`-Class is not the place where you fetch your data, except in a `choice_query`-element property. The documentation gives many examples on how to fetch data in a Form if required.

Comment: At the end of the day, it really helps you and you benefit from using the offered methods. And you will enjoy :)